# DDR2 SDRAM with the Lattice ECP5

Tags: fpga, sdram, ddr2, dll, ecp5

I have a FPGA design that requires some memory. I'd really like to use DDR2 because of cost and speed reasons. I'd be running it at its lowest allowed frequency of 125MHz. Now the ECP5 has some IP Blocks that delay the DQS strobe to latch the incoming data when reading.

However this DQS-Logic seems to work only with the IDDR Cells in x2 gearing mode, which makes everything a bit fumbly. However it also supports generic ddr interfaces where the data is edge aligned with the clock. Since i am only operating at 125MHz i'd rather use that. The IP blocks used for this application are DDRDLLA which seems to be a self contained DLL that figures out the delay codes used in the DLLDELD delay lines. Now my Plan is to just clock the DDRDLLA from my Main clock of 125MHz, let it figure out the delaycode necessary and then just route the DQS through the DLLDELD block to an IDDRX1F cell that latches in the read data from the Memory. Only trouble is in the manual (page 16) it shows the clock input being connected to the DLLDELD block whose output is then clocking DDRDLLA forming a sort of loop. Now I've done a little experiment with a MACHXO2 which seems to contain similar ip blocks and i was able to use the DLLDELD block as i intended to. Now has any of you tried this operation i am planning on an ECP5 and can tell me if it would work? Also if anyone has implemented a DDR2 Interface using the DQS Logic with the x2 gearing IDDR primitives?